# Pygame Score Update During the Collision When Using collide_rect

Tags: python, pygame

In my Pygame, I want the score to update only once when colliding(not continuous increment to a very large number in a short time). The score will update again after the one sprite completely leaves the collision area and re-enters, so the score will not update during the collision. Is there an efficient solution in Pygame?

Thanks!

Comment: Yes, but we can't do anything without seeing your code.

Comment: Please read [How do I ask a good question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and [How to create a Minimal, Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's difficult to answer without any code, but what you could do is store a variable and hold True in it. If the variable is True and you are colliding with something, increase the score and set the variable to False. Then, when it isn't colliding anymore, you could set the variable to True again.

For example:

```
var = True
if colliding and var:
    score += 1
    var = False
elif not colliding:
    var = True
```